# combining rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data frame

```
Date         CUSIP   Asset   Liability
01-01-1990     A       1        NaN
01-01-1990     A      Nan        2
02-01-1990     A       3         2
01-01-1990     B      Nan        2
01-01-1990     B       1         2
```

Is there anyway of combining this such that it becomes:

```
Date         CUSIP   Asset   Liability
01-01-1990     A       1         2
02-01-1990     A       3         2
01-01-1990     B       1         2
```

The way I came up with is to use groupby(["CUSIP", Date]).agg(function)

where I apply a function where the max(nan, 3) = 3.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df.groupby(['Date', 'CUSIP']).apply(lambda group: group.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
         Date CUSIP Asset  Liability
0  01-01-1990     A     1          2
2  02-01-1990     A     3          2
3  01-01-1990     B     1          2
```

Comment: yes! the problem with implementing a max with nan method is that this is stupidly slow. One needs to loop through a list and discard nan values. I sometimes hates the way python treats nan...

Comment: To ensure there are no errors in your data, you can also ensure that there is only one CUSIP on any given date.  Assuming the result above is called `result`, then `result.groupby(['Date', 'CUSIP'])['CUSIP'].count().max()` should return 1.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I am running this. this is very slow. are forward fill and backward fill always this slow?

Comment: What is the output of `df.info()`?  Are the columns `Asset` and `Liability` floats? And what is the type of the `Date` column?  Also, `drop_duplicates` may be slowing it down.  Try without it and see if there is an improvement.  If so, and you've checked your data to ensure there are no dups per my comment above, you can group again.  `df.groupby(['Date', 'CUSIP']).apply(lambda group: group.ffill().bfill()).groupby(['Date', 'CUSIP']).first()`

Comment: RangeIndex: 501896 entries, 0 to 501895
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Date     501896 non-null datetime64[ns]
CUSIP    501372 non-null object
Asset      386228 non-null float64
Liability      385416 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), object(1)